# Where can I find Toll Cost Extension HERE API docs?

Tags: here-api

I need to implement a toll for calculating the route, and I wanted to use Toll Extension like described [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/geovisualization/industry_fleet/optimal-routing). But I can't find documentation for this API. Any information about it redirects to [Fleet Telematics API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/calculation-considerations.html).
I would like to avoid having to implement the whole Fleet Telematics API or guessing what are the Toll Cost Extension's API parameters from the example in the first link.

I am looking for an answer that will point me to official docs or any official info saying this is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check this toll cost API documentation if this accomplish your task.

```
https://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&waypoint0=49.33729606975952,0.5986232869327068
&waypoint1=49.493527937780975,0.10129541603788539
&mode=fastest;car
&cost_optimize=1
```

Link to the docs is [here](http://documentation.developer.here.com/pdf/routing_road_pricing_hlp/2.5.10/Fleet%20Telematics%20Toll%20Costs%20v2.5.10%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Would like to highlight one problem - if you choose to just calculate toll based on existing route you may face the issue with too long url on their NGINX side. Also this API (TCE) seems to be deprecated, so it may be inevitable (unfortunately) to use fleet API.

In fleet API most params are the same like in TCE/Route API, some result are hidden via `attributes`. More on https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html. Worth to mention is that at least for now is it very expressive and there is a limited option to change this. For example, my TCE toll response has about 10k lines of formated json... whereas the same for fleet has 300k because there is no option (with `routeMatch=1` to remove links/waypoints.

From my already quite long experience with Here API as a whole, it requries some time to go deep into it... and find things.